# virtual appliance or disk image--which is more likely to run after a couple decades

Tags: virtual-machine, operating-systems

I enjoy playing with the many emulators of old operating systems, but I would really like to be playing with my own old installations from the 80s and 90s. So, I am trying to allow myself the possibility of doing so in the future. Two possibilities I can think of are 1) create a "virtual appliance" using e.g. vmware's software, and hope that the player for the software is still available for computers after another 20 or 30 years or 2) create a complete disk image and hope that a tool will be available to create a virtual appliance at that time.

With 1), I only need a player in the future, but it has to be a player compatible with the appliance format I choose now. With 2), I will need both software to create the appliance and a player, though I would not be tied to any particular standard as in 1). I am inclined to think if someone in the future is going to create a player, they will also have an appliance creator, so I am leaning toward 2) as the safer bet.

Has someone figured out a good analysis?

Comment: You want us to predict what x86 application will still work in a couple decades?  What you want isn’t possible.  We cannot even predict how long 32-bit applications, will be supported by Intel, let alone predict what file formats VMWare software will support in a couple decades.  This question beyond the scope of this community.  We can only answer practical questions

Comment: @Ramhound This is certainly a practical question--I gave an application right in the description. Perhaps you mean this is a hard question to answer. Because you find such a prediction difficult, why do you assume everyone else does?

Comment: The chances of 32-bit software, running on x86 hardware in 10 years, is very unlikely.  To put it into perspective, the next version of VMWare Workstation is 32-bit software.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree it is unlikely to run 32-bit software in 10 years is unlikely. That is the point of a hypervisor, all vmware would need to do is release a new player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use VMware Workstation and have since VMware Workstation V1.

I have the following machines all working today.

Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, Windows Vista Business 64-bit, Windows XP 32-bit, Windows 2000 32-bit, Windows NT4 32-bit, Windows 98, Windows 95, Windows 3.1, and MS DOS 6 16-bit

Kali Linux 2020 64-bit, Ubuntu 18 64-bit.

That is quite a few machines spanning more than 30 years.

I cannot say what VMware will support in the next 20 years as I do not know what operating systems will surface in the next 20 years.

However, their track record for the past 30 years has been excellent.

I should add that the machines above were created in VMware Workstation of the time and ported forward through all the versions, making machine hardware version upgrades as necessary. My Windows 7 machine is still hardware compatibility version 9 and it works fine.

I suggest you adopt VMware Workstation V15 (current) as it appears to be the most flexible going backward. Certainly I have been happy with it.

Comment: "were created in VMware Workstation of the time" You mean at the time of, e.g., MS DOS 6? I agree that is very encouraging.

Comment: Yes. But the MS-DOS machine comes along with me and still runs in VMware V15.  You need to load up the machines you want and see how it all works.